# iOS :: Web site does not work in iOS Safari and UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, uiwebview

I have an app with UIWebView, which loads a web site https://app.bridallive.com/. Previously it was working well in iPad, but now it does not.
It loads neither in UIWebView (in a simplest possible app) and in iOS Safari. Works well in Mac OS.
I tried to diagnose it with:

```
-(void) loadWebSite {
    NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://app.bridallive.com/#/dashboard?iPadApp=true"];
    NSURLRequest * request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [self.webView loadRequest: request];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self loadWebSite];
}

- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Error : %@",error);
}
```

NSAppTransportSecurity is set to YES and the web site has valid and trusted certificate.

this is what I used in futher experiments:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self loadWebSite];
}
```

but this does not give any errors.

Can anyone suggest a way to diagnose this in iOS?

Best regards,
Andrey

Comment: have you enabled `NSAppTransportSecurity` flag?

Comment: Yes this is flag is set to YES and the web site has trusted and correct SSL certificate.

Comment: can you show the code, with what you are trying to open the `url`?

Comment: `-(void) loadWebSite {
    NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://app.bridallive.com/#/dashboard?iPadApp=true"];
    NSURLRequest * request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [self.webView loadRequest: request];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    [self loadWebSite];
}
`
I also tried:
`
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [self loadWebSite];
}
`

Comment: and the `loadWebSite` function in a bit more detail?

Comment: I put the full code above.

-(void) loadWebSite {
        NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://app.bridallive.com/#/dashboard?iPadApp=true"];
        NSURLRequest * request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        [self.webView loadRequest: request];
    }

    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        
        [self loadWebSite];
    }

    -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
        [super viewWillAppear:animated];
        
        [self loadWebSite];
    }

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

UIWebview has a protocol, `UIWebViewDelegate`, it helps you to observe changes in your 
It implements a few method using what you can observe the changes in your UIWebview loading lifecyclye:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    NSLog(@"shouldStart");
    return true;
}

- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    NSLog(@"webViewDidStartLoad");
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    NSLog(@"webViewDidFinishLoad");
}

- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"%@", error);
    NSLog(@"didFailLoadWithError");
}
```

In order to receive the callback on this functions, sign up for the delegate on your classes interface in `.h` for example.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>

@end
```

I have set up a sample project, and upon opening the URL, i receive the following error in the `didFailLoadWithError` callback:

> Error Domain=WebKitErrorDomain Code=101 "(null)"

It seems you are not encoding you request properly. You should encode the string the following way:

```
NSString *encodedString=[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://app.bridallive.com/#/dashboard?iPadA‌​pp=true"] stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLFragmentAllowedCharacterSet]];
    NSURL *weburl = [NSURL URLWithString:encodedString];
```

[image]

Comment: This is what I've done.
As I mentioned the app was fully working previously.
I suspect that this could be a problem of iOS 10.x or XCode 8.

Other URLs like say https://google.com work well

Comment: thank you, but this does not work too.
Moveover this makes things worse -- neverending loading screen like on your screen shot.

Finally I found an error switching languages in iPad -- looks like there is an error in the site JavaScript. I found the issue enabling Develper console in Mac OS Safari and connecting to iPad's Safari.

Thank you very much anyway.